# pyrouge: 'pyrouge_set_rouge_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, module, installation

I have Windows 7 and use Python 2.7.  I recently installed ROUGE (Recall-Oriented Understudy for Gisting Evaluation) in order to evaluate summaries that I have.

Unfortunately, my summaries are in .txt format, and wouldn't work with ROUGE.  I therefore, installed pyrouge from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge/0.1.2).

In the same website above, they have installation steps.  I followed the first step, which was to use pip install.  The next step says:

> "Assuming a working ROUGE-1.5.5. installation, tell pyrouge the ROUGE path with this command:
>
> pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory"

I try that line in the command prompt:

> pyrouge_set_rouge_path C:\rouge

Yet I keep getting this error:

> 'pyrouge_set_rouge_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
set pyrouge_set_rouge_path=C:\rouge
```

Answer (score 2):

Although it is an old questions, there are probably still people looking for the answer.

"Assuming a working ROUGE-1.5.5. installation" does not correspond to your pyrouge installation. It references to the following. (Maybe you got that right immediately, I did not)
https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge/tree/master/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5

pyrouge_set_rouge_path is a script, not a variable you have to set.
The script is located at Python_PATH\Scripts.
Hence try something like:

```
python Python_PATH\Scripts\pyrouge_set_rouge_path C:\rouge
```