# set pyrouge_set_rouge_path error

Tags: python, windows, installation, summarization

I have Windows 7 and use Python 3.4

I'm trying to work with ROUGE installing pyrouge from pypi.

I followed the installation steps on the site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge/0.1.2

But the command:

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory
```

doesn't execute.

I try in the command prompt:

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path C:\rouge
```

and the error:

```
'pyrouge_set_rouge_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I would greatly appreciate if you can help me with something.
Thanks

Comment: Try restarting the terminal.

Comment: I think I have the solution.

The command line is not complete on the site. In my case:
command> python pyrouge_set_rouge_path c:\local\to\Rouge

Comment: The command on the site works on linux systems because they look at the first line (shebang) in the script to decide which program to open the script with, but windows doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490457/pyrouge-pyrouge-set-rouge-path-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c) for Python 2.7 in stackoverflow, and received the following answer:

```
set pyrouge_set_rouge_path=C:\rouge
```

This worked for me.