# installing pyrouge gets error in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, summarization, rouge

i wants to install pyrouge in Ubuntu for the purpose of text summarization evaluation. i use the instructions in [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge/0.1.0).

first i wrote `pip install pyrouge` then i must write this command: `pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory`.

In my system i wrote:

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge
```

and get this:

> Exception: Cannot set data directory because the path
>   /home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge/data
>   does not exist.

and also

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /home/afsharizadeh/pyrouge-0.1.0/pyrouge
```

and get this:

> Exception: Cannot set data directory because the path
>   /home/afsharizadeh/pyrouge-0.1.0/pyrouge/data does not exist.

and also

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /home/afsharizadeh/pyrouge-0.1.0/pyrouge/test
```

and get this:

> Exception: ROUGE binary not found at
>   /home/afsharizadeh/pyrouge-0.1.0/pyrouge/test/ROUGE-1.5.5.pl. Please
>   set the correct path by running pyrouge_set_rouge_path
>   /path/to/rouge/home.

i know that similar questions about this problem, was asked in stack overflow but i cant solve my problem because i don't know at all what is meant by this expression "ROUGE path". what is meant by "path to ROUGE-1.5.5"?

i know i have two directories about pyrouge. one of them is this path: `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyrouge` and the other is the directory that i was downloaded it from site. this path is: `~/pyrouge-0.1.0`. this directory has three other directories whit names: bin, pyrouge, pyrouge.egg-info.

based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173692/set-pyrouge-set-rouge-path-error) i wrote in this format:

```
set pyrouge_set_rouge_path=/home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyroug
```

after this kind of format,no errors appear but when after that i type:

```
python -m pyrouge.test
```

i get this error:

> Exception: Cannot set data directory because the path
>   /home/afsharizadeh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyroug/data
>   does not exist.
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 11 tests in 0.592s
>
> FAILED (errors=9)

what should i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the latest version of pyrouge on [Github repo](https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge), the issue was solved. For this purpose, I replaced the following commands:

```
pip install pyrouge
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory
python -m pyrouge.test
```

with these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge
cd pyrouge
python setup.py install
pyrouge_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory
python -m pyrouge.test
```

After doing this, Everything goes Okay and I get this successful message of testing:

```
Ran 11 tests in 6.322s
OK
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Note that you need to install the [official version of ROUGE](https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge/tree/master/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5) metric to get pyrouge working.

Comment: A bit strange. I get the same error even by installing the latest version. Did you get past that error? Did you do anything more than these you mentioned?

Comment: This. This answer is the perfect tutorial on how to get pyrouge working.

I met a problem : `pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/pyrouge_set_rouge_path' not found` when setting the rouge path.

To fix it, I removed my old pyrouge (installed with pip) : `pip uninstall pyrouge`

And change the cmd `python setup.py install` into `pip install -e .`

Comment: For completion, you might still have some issue following the steps of this answer. Here is the links to refer :
https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge/issues/27
https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge/issues/8

Answer (score 18):

All the steps to follow (only for Linux):

#### Step 1 : Install Pyrouge from source (not from `pip`)

```
git clone https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge
cd pyrouge
pip install -e .
```

#### Step 2 : Install official ROUGE script

```
git clone https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge.git rouge
```

#### Step 3 : Point Pyrouge to official rouge script

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path ~/pyrouge/rouge/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5/
```

*The path given to pyrouge should be absolute path !*

#### Step 4 : Install libxml parser

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge/issues/27), you need to install libxml parser :

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl
```

#### Step 5 : Regenerate the Exceptions DB

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge/issues/8), you need to regenerate the Exceptions DB :

```
cd rouge/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5/data
rm WordNet-2.0.exc.db
./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/buildExeptionDB.pl ./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions ./smart_common_words.txt ./WordNet-2.0.exc.db
```

#### Step 6 : Run the tests

```
python -m pyrouge.test
```

You should see :

> Ran 11 tests in 6.322s
>   OK

Comment: Thank you very much @Astariul. Problem solved thanks to your kind explanatory steps

Answer (score 0):

you need the following packages in CentOS:

`sudo yum install "perl(XML::LibXML)"`

`yum install perl-DB_File`