# Pyrouge installation test results in "FAILED (errors=10)"

Tags: python-2.7, module, installation, pypi, summarization

In a previous question I posted in Stackoverflow, I asked about Pyrouge installation.  After receiving the answer, I applied it.  From the [pypi installation steps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge/0.1.0), I did

```
pip install pyrouge
```

Then (here is where I substituted the pypi original step 2,

```
pyrouge_set_rouge_path.py /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory
```

with the answer I received from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490457/pyrouge-pyrouge-set-rouge-path-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c)):

```
set pyrouge_set_rouge_path=C:\rouge
```

Then, I ran the following command to make sure it installed correctly:

```
python -m pyrouge.test
```

I was supposed to receive the following output:

```
Ran 10 tests in 3.753s
OK
```

But instead got the following output:

```
Ran 10 tests in 0.034s
FAILED (erros=10)
```

Above that I received an Error for every test attempt.

```
Error1: test_config_file (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error2: test_convert_summaries (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error3: test_evaluation (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error4: test_options (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error5: test_paths (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error6: test_rouge_for_plain_text (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error7: test_text_conversion (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error8: test_write_config (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error9: test_wrong_model_pattern (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)

Error10: test_wrong_system_pattern (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
```

The following are the detailed first and last errors:

First Error:
"""

```
EEEEEEEEEE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_config_file (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\tests\Rouge155_test.py", line 138,
 in test_config_file
    rouge = Rouge155()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 88, in __init__

    self.__set_rouge_dir(rouge_dir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 402, in __set_r
ouge_dir
    self._home_dir = self.__get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 416, in __get_r
ouge_home_dir_from_settings
    with open(self._settings_file) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\IQ\\AppData\\Roaming\
\pyrouge\\settings.ini'
```

"""

Last Error:
"""

```
ERROR: test_wrong_system_pattern (pyrouge.tests.Rouge155_test.PyrougeTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\tests\Rouge155_test.py", line 59,
in test_wrong_system_pattern
    rouge = Rouge155()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 88, in __init__

    self.__set_rouge_dir(rouge_dir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 402, in __set_r
ouge_dir
    self._home_dir = self.__get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 416, in __get_r
ouge_home_dir_from_settings
    with open(self._settings_file) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\IQ\\AppData\\Roaming\
\pyrouge\\settings.ini'
```

"""

I have opened the directory: C:\Users\IQ\AppData\Roaming\pyrouge\, but it was empty.
I would like to know what it is that is wrong, and how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried just making an empty file called settings.ini in that directory?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I still receive the FAILED (errors=10).  Instead of the final IOERROR in the end, I'm getting:   File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
NoSectionError: No section: u'pyrouge settings'

Comment: user1799092 did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the answer to your initial question:

"Assuming a working ROUGE-1.5.5. installation" does not correspond to your pyrouge installation. It references to the following. (Maybe you got that right immediately, I did not)
https://github.com/andersjo/pyrouge/tree/master/tools/ROUGE-1.5.5

pyrouge_set_rouge_path is a script, not a variable you have to set.
The script is located at Python_PATH\Scripts.
Hence try something like:

```
python Python_PATH\Scripts\pyrouge_set_rouge_path C:\rouge
```

Alternatively you can create a file settings.ini at the corresponding location with this content:

```
[pyrouge settings]
home_dir = C:\rouge
```

Where C:\rouge should be the location of the file ROUGE-1.5.5.pl

Answer (score 1):

You should first install ROUGE-1.5.5 by following [this tutorial](http://www.summarizerman.com/post/42675198985/figuring-out-rouge). Only the two commands to install and no configuration is needed. Keep in mind to generate the wordnet bd file. by running

```
./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions/buildExeptionDB.pl ./WordNet-2.0-Exceptions ./smart_common_words.txt ./WordNet-2.0.exc.db
```

Under the data directory.

Then install the pyrouge from [source](https://github.com/bheinzerling/pyrouge). Remember to comment out the print lines which will trigger errors.

Then all will just goes fine.

Comment: the link in your answer has been replaced by a spam site

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 Thanks for figuring out that. Sadly the tutorial is gone and I cannot find that, but here is an alternative: https://poojithansl7.wordpress.com/2018/08/04/setting-up-rouge/